# Can't import Context into my android library

Tags: android, android-context, android-library

What dependencies I have to add to use Context in my library?

[image]

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: It should already be there, if this is a `com.android.library` module, as your `build.gradle` shows. That auto-complete would be what I would expect from a plain Java module.

Comment: Yeah, I can't import any of Android base classes. So you are telling me it "should" work based on my gradle config, there are no additional steps I have missed?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in the module setup. This is going to sound silly, but are you sure that the class in question is in the module with this `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I triple checked.